# How to lose weight?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, fat

Its been 4 years that i want to lose 6
10 kg... my height is 182 cm and my weight is 82 kg. I want, to start with, loose 5 kg... but i'm patient, i wait and years after years i lost 0.
It seems to be possible to loose weight in 5 days only, so its probably quickrr than i thought ?
Then, what is the best method to loose weight ? I am always hungry, i eat all along the day...
Is the answer : When I hungry, i prevent myself from eating, i force to keep hungry without eating, then i lose weight ?
Because i do a lot of sport but i eat too often and the problem is eating for me...

Comment: This is a very specific question that cannot be answered generically.  Each of us uses calories and nutrients differently.  You should consult with a medical professional who knows your personal history.

Answer (score 2):

If you're main problem is wrestling with a large appetite then there are 2 mains things I would suggest:

1. As you've said, you are willing to be patient, so I would reccomend only using a small deficit. That is, find your TDEE/maintenance calories and subtract 200-300. It will make the weight loss slower but a smaller deficit will be easier and therfore more sustainable.
2. Eat more foods that are less calorie dense, more filling and higher thermic affect. Low calorie foods would would be things like vegetables, fruit, oats with water, low fat Greek yoghurt. Foods high in protein, in general, are a good choice. Protein is not only quite filling, but also has a high thermic affect. That means it takes a lot of energy to break down the proteins into smaller usable molecules, and the net calorie gain is only about 70-75% of the consumed calories.

Forcing yourself not to eat is one thing I would not suggest. Trying to suppress your appetite forcefully will just make you more hungry, make the diet harder and eventually and eventually lead to failure.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest for you a diet low in carbohydrates and high in fats. Make sure you eat the right fats, this is extremely important. Avoid seed oils (canola, peanut, soybean, etc) at all costs! They are the most dangerous foods in the modern food supply. Get your fat intake from mainly animal foods and dairy if you can tolerate it. You can have some plant fats like coconut oil or olive oil, nuts and seeds, but don't overdue it.
I recommend watching this documentary, it explains why energy from carbs is more easily converted to fat: https://youtu.be/xyNHvogMFDI?si=5rBUTzRvFsBf5p1w

The fact that you are always hungry tells me you have a high carb diet. Carbs, especially the more processed/refined ones, will raise you blood sugar level quickly. They give you short bursts of energy. Fats will give you a slow burn of energy, keeping you satiated longer and allowing you to eat fewer meals.

I think it would be very hard to put on weight when you are already obese on this diet. It's very likely you lose weight, even without increasing exercise. You can go even further and cut out carbs completely, and this will be even better for losing weight.